# Automatic insertion of multiline declaration comments

Tags: emacs, comments

Have anybody extended `comment-dwim` to automagically insert a multi-line comment like

```
/** ...
 */
void foo
{
}
```

if the cursor is currently in front of a function/variable definition/declaration?

I realize that the challenge here is context detection; could a call to `end-of-defun()` followed by a call to `beginning-of-defun()` be used here?

Comment: It's presumably no less work for Emacs, but if you want to test the very beginning of the defun, you could test `(eq (point) (car (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'defun)))`. Perhaps preceded by `(while (comment-forward 1))`, and all wrapped in a `save-excursion` I imagine.